# The parameter Node is not a child of this Node error in IE

Tags: javascript, xml

I have two tag K and F. Every K tag has some child F tag. I want to remove child F tag from the K tag. Here is my code. My code is working fine in Chrome Showing error in IE

**Error : The parameter Node is not a child of this Node.**

Here is my Code

```
if(KTagNode[j].getAttribute('pview') == 198) {
    var fTagData = KTagNode[j].getElementsByTagName('F');
    for(var k=0; k<fTagData.length;k++){
         if(fTagData[k].getAttribute('N') == "USA"){
            KTagNode[j].removeChild(fTagData[k]);
            k--;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns a _live_ node list, so by removing elements inside the loop, you are changing what the loop is looping over while looping over it, which can easily lead to problems. Whether that is the issue here is impossible to tell, because you did not provide a [mcve]. But the general recommendation for such a case would be to loop through the nodes in reverse order - that way, removing an element does not influence what you will loop over after that.

Answer (score 0):

I come out with idea of this. Please check.

```
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
        //...
    ]
});
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields:[ 'name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
        { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
        { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
        { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
    ]
});
var root = {
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
        text: "Configure Application",
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: "Manage Application",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "Scenario",
            leaf: true
        }]
    }, {
        text: "User Configuration",
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: "Manage User",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "User rights",
            leaf: true
        }]
    }, {
        text: "Test Configuration",
        //leaf: true,
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: "Manage User",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "User rights",
            leaf: true
        }]
    }]
};

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    title: 'Border Layout',
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
        title: 'north Region is resizable',
        region: 'north',     // position for region
        xtype: 'panel',
        height: 50,
        split: true,         // enable resizing
        margin: '0 5 5 5',
        layout: {
        type: "hbox",
        align: "stretch"
        },
        items:[
            {
             xtype: 'combobox',
             label: 'Choose State',
             queryMode: 'local',
             displayField: 'name',
             valueField: 'abbr',
             width : 200,
            store: states,
        },{
             xtype: 'combobox',
             label: 'Choose State2',
             queryMode: 'local',
             displayField: 'name',
             valueField: 'abbr',
             width : 200,
             store: states
        }]
    },{
        title: 'West Region is collapsible',
        region:'west',
        xtype: 'panel',
        margin: '5 0 0 5',
        width: 200,
        collapsible: true,   // make collapsible
        id: 'west-region-container',
        layout: {
            type: "vbox",
            align: "stretch"
        },
        items:[{
            xtype: 'panel',
            width : 200,
            margin: '5 0 0 5',
            layout: {
                type: "vbox",
                align: "stretch"
            },
            items:[{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                label: 'Choose State',
                queryMode: 'local',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'abbr',
                width : 50,
                store: states,
            },{
                xtype: 'datefield',
                anchor: '100%',
                fieldLabel: 'To',
                name: 'to_date',
                value: new Date()
            },{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                width   : 150,
                items:[{
                    text: 'Button1'
                },{
                    text: 'Button2'

                }]
            }]
        },{
            xtype: 'treepanel',
            useArrows: true,
            autoScroll: false,
            animate: true,
            enableDD: false,
            title: 'Configuration',
            width: 200,
            height: 400,
            rootVisible: false,
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
                root: root
            }),
            listeners: {
                itemclick: function(s, r) {
                    alert(r.data.text);
                }
            }
        }]


    },{
        title: 'Center Region',
        region: 'center',     // center region is required, no width/height specified
        xtype: 'panel',
        margin: '5 5 0 0',
        layout: {
            type: "vbox",
            align: "stretch"
            },
        items:[{
            xtype: 'grid',
            title: 'Simpsons',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
            columns: [
                { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
                { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
                { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
            ],
            height: 150,
            width: 400,
        },{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                width   : 150,
                items:[{
                    text: 'Button1'
                },{
                    text: 'Button2'

                }]
            },{
                xtype : 'panel',
                width: 175,
                height: 150,
                bodyPadding: 10,
                title: 'Final Score',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Home',
                    name: 'home_score',
                    value: '10'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Visitor',
                    name: 'visitor_score',
                    value: '11'
                }],
            }]
    },{
        title: 'South Region is resizable',
        region: 'south',     // position for region
        split: true,         // enable resizing
        margin: '0 5 5 5',
        xtype: 'toolbar',
            items:[{
                text: 'Button1'
            },{
                text: 'Button2'

            }]
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```